# Comparing the length of a string to a number. Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-5, comparison

I need to compare the length of a string to the number of seats entered and give an error if the length is greater. I'm using a has_and_belongs_to_many association.

I have a flights table and passengers table, they are joined together by a flights_passengers table in order for passengers to be added to a new flight.

I'm having trouble with the correct way to call the passengers string and compare its length to the number of seats entered.

Seats is an integer value.

```
class Flight < ApplicationRecord
 validate :num_passengers

 def num_passengers
  if passenger.passenger_id.length > seats
   errors.add(:seats, "must be more than passengers")
  end
 end

end
```

form.html.erb (how passengers are added to new flight)

```
<label><%= form.label :passengers %></label>
    <%= collection_select(:passenger, :passenger_id, Passenger.all, :id, :first_name, {}, { :multiple => true } )%>
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "flights", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "origin"
 t.string "destination"
 t.string "dep_time"
 t.string "arr_time"
 t.integer "seats"
 t.integer "price"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.integer "airline_id"
 t.index ["airline_id"], name: "index_flights_on_airline_id"
end

create_table "flights_passengers", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer "flight_id", null: false
 t.integer "passenger_id", null: false
 t.index ["flight_id", "passenger_id"], name: "index_flights_passengers_on_flight_id_and_passenger_id"
 t.index ["passenger_id", "flight_id"], name: "index_flights_passengers_on_passenger_id_and_flight_id"
end 

create_table "passengers", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "first_name"
 t.string "last_name"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all about data type. It is impossible to know the length of a digit, you must convert the value to a string, with `to_s`:

```
def num_passengers
  if passenger.passenger_id.to_s.length > seats
   errors.add(:seats, "must be more than passengers")
  end
end
```